# How to get logs to show up as errors in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When an error occurs in my cloud function it is not showing up in the firebase console or logs as an error.

I would like the error to show up on the health tab of functions page in the Firebase console so I am aware of the error.
Currently it only shows up in the function logs as a normal log entry (see image).
[image]

How can I adjust my code so that an error occurs in the cloud function so I can see it.
Note that this function is called by a webhook from Stripe.

```
export const stripeWHEInvoiceCreated = functions
  .region('us-east1')
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      (req as any).rawBody,
      sig,
      webhookSecretInvoiceCreated
    );
    await internalInvoiceCreated(event);

    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});

export const internalInvoiceCreated = async(event: any) => {
  try {
     // Do stuff
 } catch(err) {
    console.log('An error occurred');
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }

  return;
}
```

Comment: The `try-catch` in Cloud function should catch any error thrown within `internalInvoiceCreated` so you should need `try-catch` in that function. You can simply `throw new Error('Intentional Error')` from that function. Then `console.log(err)` in catch of main cloud function.

Comment: Are you saying that you expect `res.status(400).send(err)` to log something?  Or are you saying that the console logs you have right now are not displaying?  Please edit the question to clarify what exactly is not working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have updated the question. I would like the error to show up on the health tab of functions page in the Firebase console so I am aware of the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is use `console.error()` instead of `console.log()`.

If you want to do logging the best possible way, you should use the logging functions of the functions SDK, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs).

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
functions.logger.error(...);
```

Comment: "Use console.error" - I've not found this to work. If I do console.error in a cloud function, it just looks identical to a console.log. Both come out as a "info" type, and AFAIK doesn't everything get sent to stderr in the node cloudfunctions runtime anyway?